# some CATransition string types do not work

Tags: iphone

I tested CATransition string types as below

```
@"suckEffect"
@"spewEffect"
@"genieEffect"
@"unGenieEffect"
@"rippleEffect"
@"twist"
@"tubey"
@"swirl"
@"charminUltra"
@"zoomyIn"
@"zoomyOut"
```

I found that only @"suckEffect",@"rippleEffect" DO work.
All others are replaced by Fade Effect.

Even the effect of type @"suckEffect",@"rippleEffect", it looks like subtype has no function.

I do not know if what I got is right or not?

Welcome any comment.

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 4):

Kindly use this Effects

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.type = @"suckEffect"; // Change to follow types
//transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.duration = 2.0f;
transition.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
```

- `kCATransitionFade`
- `kCATransitionMoveIn`
- `kCATransitionPush`
- `kCATransitionReveal`
- `@"cameraIris"`
- `@"cameraIrisHollowOpen"`
- `@"cameraIrisHollowClose"`
- `@"cube"`
- `@"alignedCube"`
- `@"flip"`
- `@"alignedFlip"`
- `@"oglFlip"`
- `@"rotate"`
- `@"pageCurl"`
- `@"pageUnCurl"`
- `@"rippleEffect"`
- `@"suckEffect"`

Note: Click the Link to View More options

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIViewAnimationState

Comment: I am check this Effects and Add to My Application it,s work fine

Comment: *NOTE*: While these may work, any effect not defined as a constant is *undocumented*. This, in addition to the fact that you are quoting a wiki that documents jailbreak-safe features, means these may or may not, at some point in future, stop being Apple-safe and may start getting rejected by Apple.

Answer (score 1):

These transitions are all undocumented and considered "private". So there simply is no guarantee that they exist or work, and if you use them your app is likely to get rejected by Apple. But for some documentation, see the [iPhone dev wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIViewAnimationState).

Comment: I have a few apps in the app store using the "rippleEffect", so i suppose it is ok to use this effects

Comment: @DimitarMarinov Trouble is, you never know when they will break or when Apple will start detecting and rejecting apps using these.